# When is a word implied?

Tags: grammar

I was about to write an hilarious tweet, that goes

```
I change my mind as often as I change underwear, not very
```

Am I correct in thiking that the word *often* is implied at the end? or do I have to spell it out, like

```
I change my mind as often as I change underwear, not very often
```

In the latter I get the feeling that the **often** is forced, so, when is a word implied?

Comment: That's an acceptable conversational deletion.  **often** would be understood to be intended, as that adverb is the only word in the sentence that **very** could modify in the present context. The comparative **as often as** is carried forward. There are a number so-called "deletion" rules.

Comment: But I wouldn't say that **often** would be "forced", if stated explicitly in a non-joking context. What is "forced" is the delayed hilarity. The *punch line* of this kind of joke is typically punctuated by a drum roll and cymbal crash supplied by the drummer of the late night house band.

Comment: @TRomano I see, too bad my band isn't on twitter

Comment: Maybe some sound-emojis.  For this joke we'd need drums, cymbals, and groans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Punctuation is your friend here:

> I change my mind as often as I change my underwear: not very.

Think of the colon as the punctuational equivalent of a drum roll: it builds suspense, and announces that the wowzer is coming.

The word "often" isn't really "implied" here. Because the words that follow a colon describe or clarify what came before it, the reader will realize that the adverb of degree "very" can only logically apply to the adverb "often" in the independent clause.